# Using LastIndexOf and SubString in mssql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

How do I get [Result] column from [Code] column using ms sql

```
Id          Code
200001      43791
200001      67036
200006      19.09.01.08683      
200006      03.01.04.01.64230   
200007      19.01.03.02804    

Id          Result  Code
200001      43791   43791
200001      67036   67036
200006      08683   19.09.01.08683      
200006      64230   03.01.04.01.64230   
200007      02804   19.01.03.02804
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Are the last set of digits after the period always 5 digits long?

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS, not even in the title.

Comment: Yes I have tried, but couldn't solve.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
SELECT Id,
       RIGHT(Code, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + Code)) - 1) AS [Result],
       Code
FROM   YourTable
```