# What is best way to get last indexof character in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008

In C#, we have `String.LastIndexOf` method to get a last index of a particular character location for given string. Is there any similar function to do same in SQL Server. I tried using `CHARINDEX` but couldn't able to achieve it.

Comment: Hey, this "duplicated" question is for SQL Server 2008, and the other one is for SQL Server 2000. There is a difference between them.

Comment: So add an answer to the other question.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

A little tricky, but you could do something like:

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([field]),0,CHARINDEX('[char]',REVERSE([field]))))
```

Comment: I had this stashed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024978/find-index-of-last-occurrence-of-a-sub-string-using-t-sql, because it seems to come up pretty often.

Comment: The answer here is more concise and efficient: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13610627/197591

Answer (score 27):

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(32) = 'xyzxyzyyythgetdghydgsh';
SELECT LEN(@x) - CHARINDEX('y', REVERSE(@x)) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out, analyze result step by step.

```
declare @string varchar(max)
declare @subString varchar(max)
set @string = 'this is a duplicated question,      but may get some new answers, since tech chagne from time to time as we know';
set @subString = 'this is a duplicated question,      but may get some new answers, since tech chagne from time to time'
--Find the string.lastIndexof(time)
select LEN(@String)
select LEN(@SubString)
select CHARINDEX('time', REVERSE(@string))
select reverse(@string)
select reverse('time')
SELECT LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX(reverse('time'), REVERSE(@string)) - Len('time') + 1
```