# Extract string after character and before final full stop (/period) in SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle, plsql

I want to extract all of the string after, and including, 'Th' in a string of text (column called 'COL_A' and before, and including, the final full stop (period). So if the string is:

```
'3padsa1st/The elephant sat by house No.11, London Street.sadsa129'
```

I want it to return:

```
'The elephant sat by house No.11, London Street.'
```

At the moment I have:

```
substr(SUBSTR(COL_A, INSTR(COL_A,'Th', 1, 1)),1,instr(SUBSTR(COL_A, INSTR(COL_A,'Th', 1, 1)),'.'))
```

This nearly works but returns the text after and including 'Th' (which is right), but returns the text before the first full stop (period), rather than the final one. So it returns:

```
The elephant sat by house No.
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How can you decide which is the real full stop? In the example, how can you say that the stop is after "London Street." and not after "No."? Is the real full stop given by the last period in the string?

Comment: You know that if you INSTR(x,'.',-1) it will search backwards for the first period counting back from the end of the data?

Comment: ^^^This is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the full stop is given by the last period in you string, you can try with something like this:

```
select regexp_substr('3padsa1st/The elephant sat by house No.11, London Street.sadsa129', 
                     '(Th.*)\.')
from dual
```

Comment: So much cleaner than the ghastly nested SUBSTR()/INSTR()!

Answer (score 2):

From [the INSTR docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF00651), you can use a negative value of `position` to search backwards from the end of the string, so this returns the position of the last full stop:

```
instr (cola, '.', -1)
```

So you can do this:

```
substr ( cola
       , instr (cola, 'Th')
       , instr (cola, '.', -1) - instr(cola, 'Th') + 1
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is returning the position of the first period in the string. If you want it to return the position of the last period in the string try looking into reversing the string and then using `instr`.

I'm not familiar with Oracle but to give you an idea have a look at this previously answered question for SQL Server.

[What is best way to get last indexof character in SQL 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709712/what-is-best-way-to-get-last-indexof-character-in-sql-2008)

Comment: You don't need to reverse the string. If you use a negative number for the "occurance" parameter to INSTR() it will search backwards from the end of the string.

Comment: Wow thats pretty neat. For those who would like to look it up: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
instr('string', 'char', -1)
```

This would search for a `char` in the `string` from end because of the position -1.
So you can use a similar code to search for '.' from the end.

```
substr(SUBSTR(COL_A, INSTR(COL_A,'Th', 1, 1)),1,instr(SUBSTR(COL_A, INSTR(COL_A,'Th', 1, 1)),'.', -1))
```