# Extract values which do not end by specific words

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some data. It could look for example like this:

```
7   Gelb    
8   Schwarz
9   Weiß my color
10  Grau
16  Gelb I  
17  Gelb II 
18  Gelb III    
19  Gelb IV 
27  Schwarz I   
28  Schwarz II  
29  Schwarz III 
30  Schwarz IV  
31  Schwarz V   
32  Schwarz VI  
39  Weiß my color III   
40  Weiß my color IV    
41  Weiß my color V 
42  Weiß my color VI
```

As you can see, in some records we have roman numbers in convention `<name><space><roman number>`

For instance, there are *"Gelb"*, *"Weiß my color"* and *"Schwarz"* and there are also records for them in roman convention. For some, like *"Grau"*, there are no duplicates.

So there will be record with unique color name without a roman number e.g record *"Grau"* and in the table it could contain or not some records with it and roman numbers for it.

Roman numbers would be always at the end like: `<name><space><romannumber>`

My goal is only to get unique names. So out of example i want to extract only:

```
7   Gelb    
8   Schwarz    
9   Weiß my color   
10  Grau
```

How can i achieve that?

I started with this, would it be enough?

```
Select Id, Name From MyTable Where Name Not Like = '%<space><anyromancharacter>'
```

I cannot change structure of the database.

Comment: I think you should first find the last index of the whitespace. Then use the `SUBSTRING` function to get a substring from index 0 to the last index of a whitespace (if it exists. if not use the whole string). Last but not least use  `SELECT DISTINCT` to get the unique names. For finding the last index of a character you could for example look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709712/what-is-best-way-to-get-last-indexof-character-in-sql-2008

Comment: This might help: `SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE
 Name NOT LIKE '% [I II IV V VI IX X XI]%'`

Comment: Select ...
From MyTable
Where Name Not Like '%[^A-Z]%' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS          try some regex

Comment: Are there definitely no names that may resemble roman numbers? E.g. one could imagine that, in some languages, `liv` could be an actual word.

Comment: @Backtrack working nice but it will also exclude "Weiß my color". How to solve this?

Comment: @JimmyJimm   I think i have to frame the valid REGEX

Comment: @Backtrack would be nice to fix a bit your input then you could mark as answer

Comment: @JimmyJimm    Select ... From MyTable Where Name Not Like '%([IVX]+)%' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

Comment: @Backtrack not working correctly (see all records)

Comment: still not working correctly (all records)

Comment: @JimmyJimm  , Can you try this : '%\s[^A-Z]%'

Comment: not working :( (all records)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update**

```
select * from dbo.test
Where value not Like '%[MDILXV]_' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Step 1 :

```
select * from dbo.test

    id  value
    1   Gelb
    2   Gelb I
    3   Weiß my color III
    4   Weiß my color
```

When i give

```
   select * from dbo.test
    Where value not Like '%[IXLV]' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

id  value
1   Gelb
4   Weiß my color
```

Comment: @JimmyJimm, Check it now

Comment: seems now it works, but note that i can have romanian numbers even up to 4000 so not only up to X, will it also work whatever is after last space it will be excluded? e.g i can have at the end <space>MMMDLXIV

Comment: ok great, can you just explain this: MDILXV , why _ at the end and why Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS ?

Comment: Hi @JimmyJimm, The reason for _ is to match empty space at the end of the string. In the data set you have provided, When i inserted into SQL i found the empty space at the end,  Also i will match any character at the end of the string

Comment: @JimmyJimm, Consider upvoting and accepting if it looks okay

Comment: @JimmyJimm, Which part, '_' ? or entire answer ?

Comment: so you mean _ at the end of this: '%[MDILXV]_' i dont need to put it there correct? In db there will be not spaces after romanian number. But let's say it will appear one or more spaces after this will handle that or? Still dont get it.

Comment: by the way when i modified from this '%[IXLV]'  to this: '%[MDILXV]_' i get all records again.. ;/

Comment: use this ,  '%[IXLV]_' i tired to add all possible character. I will help

Comment: i think i not need this last _ if i remove it it works again. So if i am sure after romanian there will be no space is this correct to use?: '%[MDILXV]'

Comment: Ji @JimmyJimm, Okay. As i mentioned, I had some white space issue in my data set

Comment: ah ok. So should i use either this: '%[MDILXV]' or this: '%[IXLV]'

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

First, generate a list of Roman Numerals up to a specified limit. Then, extract the last *word* from your table and check if it exists in the list of Roman Numerals:

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/478805)</kbd>

```
;WITH E1(N) AS( 
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), 
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), 
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(1000)  -- Replace value inside TOP for MAX roman numbers
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
),
CteRoman(N, Roman) AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM CteTally t
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT
            REPLICATE('M', t.N/1000)
             + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                  REPLICATE('C', t.N%1000/100),
                  REPLICATE('C', 9), 'CM'),
                  REPLICATE('C', 5), 'D'),
                  REPLICATE('C', 4), 'CD')
             + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                  REPLICATE('X', t.N%100 / 10),
                  REPLICATE('X', 9),'XC'),
                  REPLICATE('X', 5), 'L'),
                  REPLICATE('X', 4), 'XL')
             + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                  REPLICATE('I', t.N%10),
                  REPLICATE('I', 9),'IX'),
                  REPLICATE('I', 5), 'V'),
                  REPLICATE('I', 4),'IV')
    ) r(a)
),
CteLastWord AS(
    SELECT *,
        LastWord = CASE 
                    WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name) = 0 THEN Name
                    ELSE REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(Name), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Name)) - 1))
                   END
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT
    id, Name    
FROM CteLastWord w
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM CteRoman
        WHERE
            Roman = w.LastWord              
    )
ORDER BY w.Id
```

Reference:

- [Convert Number to Roman Numerals in Sql Server](https://itdeveloperzone.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/convert-number-to-roman-numerals-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this. First of all create the ToRomanNumerals function from [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/philfactor/2011/09/20/roman-numerals-to-integers-and-vice-versa-in-sql/)

And now create the numbers table with the roman numbers (I have created it from 1..100) and then use the LEFT(CHARINDEX) to remove the roman numerals from the name, like this:

```
DROP TABLE #Table1

CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([ID] int, [name] varchar(17))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([ID], [name])
VALUES
    (7, 'Gelb'),
    (8, 'Schwarz'),
    (9, 'Weiß my color'),
    (10, 'Grau'),
    (16, 'Gelb I'),
    (17, 'Gelb II'),
    (18, 'Gelb III'),
    (19, 'Gelb IV'),
    (27, 'Schwarz I'),
    (28, 'Schwarz II'),
    (29, 'Schwarz III'),
    (30, 'Schwarz IV'),
    (31, 'Schwarz V'),
    (32, 'Schwarz VI'),
    (39, 'Weiß my color III'),
    (40, 'Weiß my color IV'),
    (41, 'Weiß my color V'),
    (42, 'Weiß my color VI')
;

--select name, patindex('%M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})', name) from #Table1
--select name, patindex('% [IVXLC]%', name) from #Table1

;with n as 
(select 1 as n
union all
select n.n+1 as n
from n where n < 100),
nr as
(select n, dbo.ToRomanNumerals(n) r
from n)
select name, nr.r, COALESCE(LEFT(name, PATINDEX('% ' + nr.r, name)), name) from #Table1 t
LEFT JOIN nr ON t.name LIKE '% ' + nr.r
```

Result:

```
name              r        
----------------- -------- -----------------
Gelb              NULL     Gelb
Schwarz           NULL     Schwarz
Weiß my color     NULL     Weiß my color
Grau              NULL     Grau
Gelb I            I        Gelb 
Gelb II           II       Gelb 
Gelb III          III      Gelb 
Gelb IV           IV       Gelb 
Schwarz I         I        Schwarz 
Schwarz II        II       Schwarz 
Schwarz III       III      Schwarz 
Schwarz IV        IV       Schwarz 
Schwarz V         V        Schwarz 
Schwarz VI        VI       Schwarz 
Weiß my color III III      Weiß my color 
Weiß my color IV  IV       Weiß my color 
Weiß my color V   V        Weiß my color 
Weiß my color VI  VI       Weiß my color 

(18 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: have to work on what i have, i cannot change database structure. is there really no way to extract based on this table structure? Annyway thanks for help.

Comment: I did not suggest to change the database structure

Comment: but i cannot also make functions... I have to have it in one query without functions, new tables etc.. If so i would do this ;/ that's sh** customer db

Comment: Is it just no so simple just to find last space character and if something after that exclude this record?

Comment: A function can easily be converted to a CROSS APPLY query the way Felix Pamittan made. In addition to that, you can create a function in the tempdb database and drop it afterwards. Finding last space may not work, as you need to be sure that everything that follows that last space is indeed a roman numeral

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your issue.
Add one more column in your table which contains only Roman Number of the name, if no Roman number save empty string.

```
select distinct left(NAME,LEN(NAME)-CHARINDEX(RomanNumberColumn,REVERSE(NAME))) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Weiß my` will be returned by this query.

Comment: Okay, but I guess we can't check Roman Numbers clearly in your requirement because some names end with " I" which is not a Roman in that case but it looks like Roman number and also like name.

Comment: yes for this will be wrong, and also i added distinct but still see many Gelb's, Schwarz's ... select DISTINCT left(NAME,LEN(NAME)- CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(NAME))) as Name, Id, FK_Variation_ID FROM tbVariation_Attribute  So we have still two errors to be solved.

Comment: i think we do not have to check romanian numbers i think, we have to just look for last space and if there is something after that space we have to exclude that record

Comment: @Backtrack answer is working but aso excluded "Weiß my color"

Comment: try which suits to your requirement, please check updated answer with extra column to maintain Roman Number details.

Comment: its not working also with "Weiß my color" it will be excluded

Comment: for that just add one column name like Roman Number, save the roman numbers of the name in that column, if no roman number save empty string, and replace Name column "CHARINDEX(NAME" to "CHARINDEX(RomanNumberColumn"

Comment: i cannot because i cannot change table structure have to work on what there is :(

Answer (score 0):

this should be work:

```
select distinct ID, name from YourTable
where right (name,charindex(' ',REVERSE(name))) not like '%[IVXLCDM]%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

`Where` checks only last word in `NAME` column if it contains `X V I L` characters.

Comment: no "Weiß my color" appeared after your query (note that there could be higher romanian numbers if you do this way

Comment: With this query "Weiß my color" should appear.  For higher romanian numbers you can add '%C%', '%D%' and '%M%' in 'WHERE' clause.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `cte` with your table name, same to columns. I use `id` for numeric code and `name` for names.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id,
                t.name 
FROM (
    SELECT  c1.name,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c2.name ORDER BY c1.name) as DR
    FROM cte c1
    LEFT JOIN cte c2 
        ON c2.name LIKE c1.name + '%' 
) as t
INNER JOIN cte c
    ON c.name = t.name 
WHERE t.DR = 1
```

Output:

```
id          name
----------- -----------------
7           Gelb
8           Schwarz
9           Wei? my color
10          Grau

(4 row(s) affected)
```