# sql server string split last but one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Table has a column with values

```
 ColA
------

a.b.c.d.e (car.make.model, car.la, kg)

ab.cd.ef (car.make.model)

a1.b2.c3.d4.e5(car.make.model, car.la, kg, av.vc.de)
```

I want to write a sql query to split the ColA by delimiter "." and pick last but one.

Expected output

```
Result
------
d

cd

d4
```

I have tried ParseName but dont see option to pick last but one.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a LastIndexOf in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002025/is-there-a-lastindexof-in-sql-server)

Comment: What's the purpose of the additional data posted? They don't seem to influence the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

Using Jeff Moden's [`DelimitedSplit8K`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/):

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE #Sample (ColA varchar(500));
GO
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES ('a.b.c.d.e'),
       ('ab.cd.ef'),
       ('a1.b2.c3.d4.e5');
GO

SELECT *
FROM #Sample;

WITH Split AS(
    SELECT S.ColA,
           DS.*,
           MAX(DS.ItemNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY S.ColA) AS Items
    FROM #Sample S
         CROSS APPLY DelimitedSplit8K(S.ColA,'.') DS)
SELECT Item
FROM Split
WHERE ItemNumber = Items - 1;

GO

DROP TABLE #Sample
```

Ideally, though, don't store your data in a delimited format. :)

Comment: +1 for a great answer. +1000000 for this "Ideally, though, don't store your data in a delimited format.".

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply using substring?

```
DECLARE @ColA NVARCHAR(100) = 'a1.b2.c3.d4.e5(car.make.model, car.la, kg, av.vc.de)';
SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(RIGHT(REVERSE(LEFT(@ColA, CHARINDEX('(', @ColA)-1)), LEN(LEFT(@ColA, CHARINDEX('(', @ColA)-1))-CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(LEFT(@ColA, CHARINDEX('(', @ColA)-1)))), CHARINDEX('.',RIGHT(REVERSE(LEFT(@ColA, CHARINDEX('(', @ColA)-1)), LEN(LEFT(@ColA, CHARINDEX('(', @ColA)-1))-CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(LEFT(@ColA, CHARINDEX('(', @ColA)-1)))))-1))
```

However, this last edit does NOT handle the case when there is no `.` or no `(` in the string - feel free t o extend the query accordingly

Comment: @sri I modified the query according to your last edit

Answer (score 1):

Just to play around using [**STRING_SPLIT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT ColA, t.value
FROM table1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT value, 
                   COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
            FROM STRING_SPLIT(ColA, '.')) AS t
WHERE t.rn = t.cnt - 1
```

**Note:** The function is available from SQL Server 2016.

**Note 2:** The query works provided that the function returns each value in the same order as the one it appears inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
;WITH CTE(ColA)
AS
(
SELECT 'a.b.c.d.e'      UNION ALL
SELECT 'ab.cd.ef'       UNION ALL
SELECT 'a1.b2.c3.d4.e5'
)
SELECT ColA,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(ReqColA,0,CHARINDEX('.',(ColA)))) AS ReqColA
  FROM
(
SELECT ColA ,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ColA),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(ColA))+1,LEN(REVERSE(ColA))) AS ReqColA  FROM CTE
)dt
```

Result

```
ColA            ReqColA
-----------------------
a.b.c.d.e       d
ab.cd.ef        cd
a1.b2.c3.d4.e5  d4
```