# get last _ position values in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I have one doubt in sql server .

how to get first position to  right side   specific character position.

table : empfiles

```
filename: 
ab_re_uk_u_20101001
ax_by_us_19991001
abc_20181002
```

I want output like below:

```
filename 
ab_re_uk_u
ax_by_us
abc
```

I tried like below :

```
select SUBSTRING(filename,1,CHARINDEX('2',filename) - 1)  as filename  from empfiles
```

above query is not given expected result please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server .

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39002164/5443550), which explains how to get everything to the left of the last `_` character

Answer (score 1):

If last position has always numeric values then you can use `patindex()`:

```
select *, substring(filename, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', filename)-2) as NewFile
from empfiles e;
```

If you want to get characters after than `_`  to right sight of string then you can use combo to `reverse()` and `substring()`

```
select *,
      reverse(substring(reverse(filename),charindex('_', reverse(filename))+1, len(filename)))
from empfiles e;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [reverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in combination with [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
create table f(filename nvarchar(100));
insert into f values
('ab_re_uk_u_20101001')
,('ax_by_us_19991001')
,('abc_20181002');

select 
    filename=reverse(stuff(reverse(filename),1,charindex('_',reverse(filename)),''))
from f
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
CREATE TABLE #DATA([FILENAME] NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #DATA VALUES
('ab_re_uk_u_20101001')
,('ax_by_us_19991001')
,('abc_20181002');

SELECT [filename],
       SUBSTRING([filename],0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',[filename])-1) AS ExpectedResult 
FROM #Data
```

Result

```
filename                ExpectedResult
--------------------------------------
ab_re_uk_u_20101001     ab_re_uk_u
ax_by_us_19991001       ax_by_us
abc_20181002            abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously the last position value is a date, and the format is YYYYMMDD so its 8 characters, plus, added by underscore character, so that makes its 9 character.

Assumed by the above statement applied, the following logic of the query should work

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColumnText, 1, LEN(ColumnText) - 9)
```

Which means, only display characters from character position 1, to character position LEN - 9, which LEN is the length of characters, and 9 is the last 9 digit of number to be removed

Answer (score 0):

Try with this ..

```
select [filename],SUBSTRING([filename],1,PATINDEX('%_[0-9]%',[filename])-1) from empfiles
```

Individual Select records

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ab_re_uk_u_20101001',1,PATINDEX('%_[0-9]%','ab_re_uk_u_20101001')-1)

SELECT SUBSTRING('ax_by_us_19991001',1,PATINDEX('%_[0-9]%','ax_by_us_19991001')-1)

SELECT SUBSTRING('abc_20181002',1,PATINDEX('%_[0-9]%','abc_20181002')-1)
```