# Getting rid of characters in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Management Studio 2012, I have a field which holds paths to files

```
C:/Documents/FolderA/FolderA1/FileName1
C:/Documents/FolderA/FolderA1/FileName2
C:/Documents/FolderA/FolderA1/FileName3
C:/Documents/FolderA/FileNameA
C:/Documents/FolderA/FileNameB
```

Want my field to look like this

```
C:/Documents/FolderA/FolderA1/
C:/Documents/FolderA/FolderA1/
C:/Documents/FolderA/FolderA1/
C:/Documents/FolderA/
C:/Documents/FolderA/
```

Have tried using the function left but you have to declare the amount of characters to get to delete and obviously some file name are longer than others so this doesn't work.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002025/is-there-a-lastindexof-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```
select col, replace(col, right(col, charindex('/', reverse(col) + '/' ) -1), '')
from table t;
```

This assumes `Folders` always contains filenames.

Comment: Superb, thanks so much, never come across reverse before

Comment: This is not a safe method, Imagine an imput like this: **C:/Files/Filename1/File** result: **C:/s/name1/**

Comment: @t-clausen.dk. . . Read My bottom line.

Comment: Oh, you were referring to extension. I missed that. Anyway the link from the original question has an answer handling that using a safe method.