# Trying to Split a String Into Parts by SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-function

Please Excuse me if this is Simple... I am new to SQL..I am need to Run  this Custom SQL Query to get data from Microsoft SQL Server. Here is this field

```
TitleName

abc_34235
abcd_2_56543
xyz_4532
```

I want to get a Column  with Only these Values

```
34235
56543
4532
```

Please Help
DR

Comment: what is your table name and what is this 34235 56543 4532 ?

Comment: Use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

Comment: Lets us Say TableName is Mytable...Basically, I want to get the numbers from last part of the String. In above example, I shouldf be getting 34235 from abc_34235 and only 56543 from abcd_2_56543. I hope it makes Sense.. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39002164/2055998

Comment: @drrai66 does my code work?

Comment: One More Thing...I got the values as String..How Can I get Them as Integar?

Comment: Yes Ali, Your Code also Worked...I marked it Correct, ONe more Question I asked how can I get those values as Integar. It is currently returning values as String. I want them as Integar ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you:

```
select RIGHT(TitleName,LEN(TitleName)-CHARINDEX('_',TitleName)) from Mytable
```

Comment: I think you want `_`, not `-`

Comment: Thanks Everyone...You solved my Problem..I used This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39002164/2055998

Comment: Thanks Ali..Can you advise how to get those values as Integar not as String please?

Comment: cast(yourcoulmn as int)

Comment: Where in Your Code I need to put CAST Statement..Sorry I am Totally New..

Comment: for example : select cast(right(db_name(), charindex('_', reverse(db_name()) + '_') - 1)as int) from mytable

Comment: Never mind..I got it. I am using Tableau to create Joins. I could Convert it there and it worked..Thanks and Regards to all