# Obtain everything from string after last underscore in every string

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract everything from my list of strings after the last underscore, after `MOB_` in big query.

See example below:

STRING:

```
Topshop_AW19_Pro_MOB_competitors(mid price point)custom_affinity
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
competitors(mid price point)custom_affinity
```

Comment: The last understand is in "customer_affinity", so I would expect "affinity" as the desired output.

Comment: Apologies i would like everything after MOB_

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002025/

Comment: So the everything after the last `_` and before `(` if it exists?

Comment: Does `_(?:[^_]+\(.*|[^_]+)$` work for you? - just remove first character from result.

Comment: STRING: LL CORPORATE_PRO_TRAFFIC_LAL 2% LLUK PIXEL USING PURCHASE_I810

Comment: REGEX USED: REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(ad_name, r'I\d+'),'','')

Comment: OUTPUT NEEDED: _I810  -  ONLY ALLOW NUMBERS TO BE EXTRACTED AFTER _I810

Comment: 2ND STRING: LL2U_CONVERSION_COMPETITORS_CS_C95_I62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the possible solutions :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(your_field, LOCATE('MOB_',your_field)+4)
FROM your_table;
```

or with regexp

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(your_field,'(?<=MOB_).*$') 
FROM your_table
```

EDIT with oracle :

```
SELECT substr(regexp_substr(your_field,'MOB_(.*)'),5) "result" FROM your_table;
```

if you don't want to use substr http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4021/20 :

```
SELECT regexp_substr(your_field,'MOB_(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) "result" FROM your_table;
```

Edit 2 with oracle :
See more examples here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4021/31
One with regexp_replace and one with instr (= find in oracle).

Comment: I don't see LOCATE in the documentation for bigquery -- that is oracle and db2 right?

Comment: ok -- also FIND https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/FIND-Function_57344729

Comment: How would i do this with the find function?

Comment: In oracle I would use instr function which is like locate and I suppose find ? See my second edit above with some more examples

Answer (score 0):

This seems direct to the point:

```
RIGHT(stuff, RIGHT_FIND(stuff, 'MOB_'))
```

Interesting the documentation seems to have some errors:

https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/RIGHT-Function_57344732

https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/RIGHTFIND-Function_118228807