# How Remove Last value from variable in ms sql

Tags: sql-server, database

How to remove last value with comma, I want to take recored only 5

```
declare @brokername1 nvarchar(max)='indiabullssecurities,canmoney,indianivesh,acumencapitalmarket,sharekhan,edelweisscapital';
print @brokername1
```

I want this string 'indiabullssecurities,canmoney,indianivesh,acumencapitalmarket,sharekhan'

Comment: reverse it, find the index of the first comma then take the characters from there to the end then reverse it back

Comment: This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002025/is-there-a-lastindexof-in-sql-server.

Comment: @cameront can you please share perfect answer.

Comment: Did you look at the link I shared? ```select left(@brokername1, len(@brokername1) - charindex(',', reverse(@brokername1) + ','))```

Comment: Thansk @nickfinity