# Get values after '.'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column like this:

```
log
---
smart.pc
mobile.my.phone
laptop.student.school
dog.house
pc.game.headset
```

And I want to take only the last values after '.':

```
log
---
pc
phone
school
house
headset
```

I tried with `case when log like '%.%'` to take the values but in the replace after I do not know what to put in the old value's place to take all the values from the column. `REPLACE(log, '', '')`

Seems it has also answered here : [Is there a LastIndexOf in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002025/is-there-a-lastindexof-in-sql-server)

Comment: So everything after the last `.`?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to use `string_split()`:

```
select s.value
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.log, '.') s
where t.log like '%.' + s.value;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c8ca1b2eac4c902091c1ea7c42d119f) is a db<>fiddle.