# Split address name from number SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Here is my column that displays the full addresses.

[image]

I want to split the name street and the number street in two separate columns. I have tried this:

```
SELECT
   substring([ObjektStr], 1, patindex('%[1-9]%', [ObjektStr])-1) as Street,
   substring([ObjektStr], patindex('%[1-9]%', [ObjektStr]), len([ObjektStr])) as HouseNumber
FROM
   table1
```

without a result. I want something to search for the name until it finds the first number. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Based on *image* of the sample data, why not just get the value after the last whitespace (`' '`)?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: [Is there a LastIndexOf in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39002025/2029983)

Comment: I get one error on a spesific address(Falkstr. 107)

Comment: *"I get one error"* Great, so debug it and fix it if you aren't going to share it. :)

Comment: The error is this: "Error converting the varchar value "Falkstr. 107" to the int data type"

Comment: The error is telling you the problem there. `'Falkstr. 107'` is definately *not* an `int`. But why are you trying to convert the values to an `int` anyway? There are clear examples of house numbers that aren't `int` values. What "int" is `'43-45'` (no, it's not `2`), or `'12a'`?

Comment: I know that are not int. My point is that I want to put all the name address of every row until it finds the first number.. should I convert all of this into "int" or "varchar" and then write a query?

Comment: None of it is an `int`, I don't know why you are converting anything to an `int`. See the accepted answer in the dupe again, it shows you exactly what you need to do. It can't produce the error you have, as it doesn't do any implicit or explicit conversion.

Comment: do you have any idea of how could I split the varchar into name address and number address?

Comment: *"do you have any idea of how could"* Yes, see my commetns above and the linked duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I saw your comments and I tried the solution you gave me [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002025/is-there-a-lastindexof-in-sql-server and I had an error as I wrote it before

Comment: I [can't replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=38740219c7ed441db6976233f21dd949) your error.