# Getting last group of number from string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this group of strings:

```
*INBOX_COL
14AF08
14AF09
17NAMX14
17NAMX16
21KMTZ7
21KMTZ8
21KMTZ9
B-09
B-14
```

Let's say that the last group of number (7, 8, 9, 14 etc) represents the size.

I want to get the last group of numbers to determine the quantity

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (RIGHT(RTRIM(INBOX_COL),2) > '16' THEN 6 ELSE 12 END QTY
FROM MY_TABLE
```

but since the writing is not uniform, so when I took the last two character of string it returns something like this = ('08', '8', '09','9', 'Z7', 'Z8') so it failed the Select Case conditions.

I want to extract the string like these:

```
14AF08 = 8
17NAMX14 = 14
21KMTZ7 = 7
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You could use the [last index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002025/is-there-a-lastindexof-in-sql-server/39002164) of a non-digit char. Otherwise just implement your own scalar function to loop from the end and extract the digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `reverse()` the string
2. use `patindex()` to find non numeric character
3. use `right()` to extract the characters

---

```
SELECT RIGHT(INBOX_COL, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(INBOX_COL)) - 1)
```

Comment: Niiiice.. simple yet met the expectation. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Not the most generic of methods, but if you knew that the largest number you are looking for is 999 then you only have to check the last 3 chars and then sub-string them out.

```
select X.INBOX_COL
  -- Substring out the number component
  -- Cheeky way to ignore dash ('-')
  , replace(substring(X.INBOX_COL, Z.StringLength-Z.NumberLength+1, Z.NumberLength),'-','') Quantity
from (
  values
  ('14AF08'),
  ('14AF09'),
  ('17NAMX14'),
  ('17NAMX16'),
  ('21KMTZ7'),
  ('21KMTZ8'),
  ('21KMTZ9'),
  ('B-09'),
  ('B-14')
) X (INBOX_COL)
cross apply (
  -- Assume max value number is 999, so check last 3 characters of string
  values (
    isnumeric(case when len(X.INBOX_COL) > 0 then substring(reverse(X.INBOX_COL),1,1) else 'z' end)
    , isnumeric(case when len(X.INBOX_COL) > 1 then substring(reverse(X.INBOX_COL),2,1) else 'z' end)
    , isnumeric(case when len(X.INBOX_COL) > 2 then substring(reverse(X.INBOX_COL),3,1) else 'z' end)
  )
) Y (One, Two, Three)
cross apply (
  -- Get the expected length of the number string (and the length of the actual string)
  values (
    len(X.INBOX_COL), case when One = 1 and Two = 1 and Three = 1 then 3 when One = 1 and Two = 1 then 2 when One = 1 then 1 else 0 end
  )
) Z (StringLength, NumberLength);
```

Returns:

| INBOX_COL | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 14AF08 | 08 |
| 14AF09 | 09 |
| 17NAMX14 | 14 |
| 17NAMX16 | 16 |
| 21KMTZ7 | 7 |
| 21KMTZ8 | 8 |
| 21KMTZ9 | 9 |
| B-09 | 09 |
| B-14 | 14 |

Comment: wow thanks for the input, I created a function based on your solution now I have another options along with @Squirrel answer to extract the data.